# Prevent recyclerview from stop scrolling on touch event

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a simple recyclerview with an adapter of strings displaying a list of numbers, i want to avoid the recyclerview to stop when it is scrolling and it's touched by the user.
I've already canceled to manually scroll the recyclerview on dragging by the user, but i need to manage the scrolling by myself programmatically (start and stop scroll)

I dont want to let the user interact with the recyclerview.
Here's a small [video](https://youtu.be/pzcr8S5r5FU) showing what happens when the user touches the recyclerview when its scrolling (it stops). I want to cancel that behaviour.

this is how i cancel scroll on dragging by the user

```
recyclerViewSlot.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            // set return "true" = disables scrolling behaviour on dragging
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
        }
    });
```

by adding these lines of code, there is no change on the behaviour.

```
recyclerViewSlot.setEnabled(false);
recyclerViewSlot.setClickable(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend the `RecyclerView` class then manually prevent `onTouch` from being called like so:

```
public class YourRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

    private boolean lock=false;
    public YourRecyclerView (Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    public YourRecyclerView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public YourRecyclerView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if(!lock){

        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }

    }


    /**
     * @return the lock
     */
    public boolean isLock() {
        return lock;
    }

    /**
     * @param lock the lock to set
     */
    public void setLock(boolean lock) {
        this.lock = lock;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Niza!, iv'e tested it and i got same results, returning true or false doesnt make any change on the behaviour. have you tested this?

Comment: You can use that code to prevent the user from scrolling the RecyclerView. If you want the user not to stop the RecyclerView when it is fringed, then you have to detect when the recyclerView has been flinged and then lock it

Comment: like this   list.addOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){

   @Override
   public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView,
     int newState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING){
     list.setLock(true);
    }
    else{
     list.setLock(false);
    }
   }});

Comment: same results, i really have tested a lot of options with no success

Answer (score 1):

Overriding onInterceptTouchEvent in a custom RecyclerView you can achieve that.

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}
```